# Use of InProc Memory for Session while using Session State in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I have an MVC3 application that until very recently has been using InProc for session management.  Due to random log-outs caused by the app-pool being recycled I am having to make the switch to the Session State method.

The problem is that I have a complex 'runtime' session variable that is not serializable.  One of the main reasons is that I have a javascript.net instance running that is used by extensively by the controllers/models.

Is there any way to keep variables like this 'InProc' while the session authentication is taken care of by the 'Session State' method?  And if I can do that, would all that data then be lost if the app-pool gets recycled (thus, really just the same problem as before).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> session authentication is taken care of by the 'Session State' method?

I'm not sure what **session authentication** means. Do you mean **Form Authentication**?

### Form Authentication

If you want to survive **FormsAuthenticationTicket** when Application Pool is recycled, you need to set [machineKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx) in web.config explicitly.

### Session State

Basically, Session-State has few [modes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.ASPX).

**InProc** mode - session state are stored in server memory. As the result, when Application Pool is recycled, they all will be deleted.

If you want to persist session state, you need to store either in **StateServer** or **SQLServer** mode.